# Using Vagrant to set up a VM with KVM/qemu without VirtualBox

Tags: vagrant, qemu, devops, vagrantfile, kvm

I'm getting started Vagrant and want to use it with KVM/qemu (and the Virtual Machine Manager GUI), instead of installing VirtualBox. So I first installed Vagrant:

```
$ vagrant --version
Vagrant 1.9.1

$ vagrant box list
There are no installed boxes! Use `vagrant box add` to add some
```

As [per](http://softwaretester.info/deploy-with-vagrant-on-kvm-libvirt/) [these](http://www.lucainvernizzi.net/blog/2014/12/03/vagrant-and-libvirt-kvm-qemu-setting-up-boxes-the-easy-way/) [posts](https://ttboj.wordpress.com/2013/12/09/vagrant-on-fedora-with-libvirt/), I require `vagrant-libvirt` for it to work with KVM, so I installed that next:

```
$ vagrant plugin list
vagrant-libvirt (0.0.37)
vagrant-share (1.1.6, system)
```

Next, I to add a CentOS(7) box using `vagrant box add "centos/7"` and selected `libvirt`, when prompted. After which, I ran `vagrant init` and didn't encounter any errors:

```
$ vagrant init centos/7
A `Vagrantfile` has been placed in this directory. You are now
ready to `vagrant up` your first virtual environment! Please read
the comments in the Vagrantfile as well as documentation on
`vagrantup.com` for more information on using Vagrant.
```

However, `vagrant up` seems to be erroring out, like so:

```
$ vagrant up
No usable default provider could be found for your system.

Vagrant relies on interactions with 3rd party systems, known as
"providers", to provide Vagrant with resources to run development
environments. Examples are VirtualBox, VMware, Hyper-V.

The easiest solution to this message is to install VirtualBox, which
is available for free on all major platforms.

If you believe you already have a provider available, make sure it
is properly installed and configured. You can see more details about
why a particular provider isn't working by forcing usage with
`vagrant up --provider=PROVIDER`, which should give you a more specific
error message for that particular provider.
```

- Here's the ***provider*** section in the `Vagrantfile`

  ```
  config.vm.provider :libvirt do |domain|
      domain.driver = "qemu"
      domain.memory = 512
      domain.cpus = 1
  end
  ```
- I tried modifying it to:

  ```
  config.vm.provider :libvirt do |domain|
      domain.driver = "kvm"
      domain.host = 'localhost'
      domain.uri = 'qemu:///system'
      domain.memory = 512
      domain.cpus = 1
  end
  ```
- I also tried `vagrant up --provider=kvm`, `vagrant up --provider=qemu`, and `vagrant up --provider=libvirt` too, to no avail.

Is there any step that I've missed? Or another package/dependency that needs to be installed?

**Edit:** After the adding `centos/7` using vagrant, it shows up when running `vagrant box list`.

```
$ vagrant box list
centos/7 (libvirt, 1611.01)
```

Comment: can you re-run `vagrant box list` after you've added the box

Comment: @FrédéricHenri `centos/7` shows up in the list. Added the output in the question

Comment: hum .. is your installation of libvirt and qemu working correctly ? are you able to create qemu or kvm type virtual machines with `virsh` or `virt-manager`

Comment: @FrédéricHenri - yes it does, though I've only used it with the GUI (VMM) thus far. `$ sudo virsh list` shows a proper output `12    SS_Work                        running`, [like so](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a4bc0e8cceacd9d653d83c2afff93dcb)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use either the command line option `--provider=kvm` or you can set the `VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER` environment variable:

```sh
export VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER=kvm  # <-- may be in ~/.profile, /etc/profile, or elsewhere

vagrant up
```

Answer (score 11):

Start vagrant box with command

```
vagrant up --provider=kvm
```

Although it has been said in https://seven.centos.org/2017/08/updated-centos-vagrant-images-available-v1707-01/ that

> The vagrant-libvirt plugin is only compatible with Vagrant 1.5 to 1.8

Comment: update 2019-07-21: quote from that vagrant-libvirt README https://github.com/vagrant-libvirt/vagrant-libvirt#installation : "Vagrant-libvirt supports Vagrant 2.0, 2.1 & 2.2. It should also work with earlier releases from 1.5 onwards but they are not actively tested."

Answer (score 1):

vagrant-libvirt(0.0.40) is compatible with Vagrant 2.0.2 if you are running Ruby 2.3, at least on Linux Mint 18.3 (Ubuntu 16.04). I used vagrant from the Debian download on the vagrantUp website and installed the plugin using it without any problem.

Comment: I don't think this is true. The [vagrant-libvirt README](https://github.com/vagrant-libvirt/vagrant-libvirt#installation) says "Vagrant-libvirt supports Vagrant 1.5, 1.6, 1.7 and 1.8". That README also recommends not installing vagrant with `yum`.

Comment: update 2019-07-21: quote from that readme: "Vagrant-libvirt supports Vagrant 2.0, 2.1 & 2.2. It should also work with earlier releases from 1.5 onwards but they are not actively tested."